# Change the title by pressing a shiny button Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Free",align = "center"),
  actionButton("go", "Go") 
 )

server <- function(input, output) {

 observeEvent(input$go,{
#change the h1 title for 
code("Busy",align="center")
}
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How to change the title when pressing a button? the idea is to change the word free to busy when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would make the `h1` header using `uiOutput` in the `ui`. Then, you can dynamically change this text to whatever you want in `server`. Perhaps for your example, you can have a `reactiveVal` that contains the text you want in the header, which can be modified in your case when the `actionButton` is pressed.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("text_header"),
  actionButton("go", "Go") 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal("Free")
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    rv("Busy")
  })
  
  output$text_header <- renderUI({
    h1(rv(), align = "center")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: i am not very familiar with reactivevalues ​​i will study further, thank you very much.